# How to upload a selenium project on github with below mentioned error?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have tried uplaoding my project using Git bash but getting an error.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1sjx.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjiQR.png)

I've also looked at the links provided so far but I'm still getting no where.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Git does not care what you put in it. Can you share the commands you are using to try and do this?

Comment: @Jacob I have already added screenshot of an error i am getting.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly seem to be very new at Git. I would HIGHLY recommend you look at a tutorial and try and understand for yourself what your problem is. With that said, here is your solution

Assuming you have properly created and committed to a local git repository, add a remote repository as such `git remote add origin https://github.com/link-to-your-git-repo.git`. Then push everything with `git push -u origin master`.

Your problem is that you have a misunderstanding of how to use the Git Bash. I highly recommend you read this at the minimum.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-The-Command-Line